# Can I use NuGet for JavaScript libraries without putting them in the top-level Scripts folder?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, nuget

I'd love to use NuGet for jQuery, jQuery UI, Modernizr, Knockout.js, and more. But NuGet wants to put the associated files in `/Scripts`, which would get way too messy. I'd much prefer them to go into `/Content/Scripts/libraries`, or at the very least `/Scripts/libraries`.

Is this possible?

Comment: I've given up using NuGet for JavaScript libraries because it gets way too messy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something the NuGet Itself does. Where files go is defined by the Packages themselves. So the Author of the package would need to change the location :-/ You could however author your own package that put the files in the right spot. http://nuget.org/Contribute/Index

Comment: This is the one thing that NuGet sucks at. It also makes it more difficult to maintain the <reference> lines in .js files.